# Google Analytics Multiple Profiles

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

We have a large number of websites (>50) which we wish to track using analytics software. We also wish to track the total number of visits across all sites from one console.

I have done some research, and the supported way to do this by google is to install one 'msater' tracking profile, and use filters to create child profiles on each domain. However, this does not allow more than 49 different sites to be created due to the 50 site maximum, which means that having about 300 sites would result in 6 'master' profiles, which then need to be manually combined.

I have also tried multiple profiles per site using custom variables, e.g.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['t1._setAccount', 'UA-xxx-01']);
_gaq.push(['t1._setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['t1._trackPageview']);

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['t2._setAccount', 'UA-xxx-02']);
_gaq.push(['t2._setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['t2._trackPageview']);
```

However I read that this may result in the data not properly being recorded, and seems to be strongly disproved of by Google.

Is there a simple way to combine multiple profiles? If possible, i'd rather stick with Google, and we're under a tight budget so can't afford the google analytics tools available.

Comment: You should really have a look to Analitycs API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, according to the official Google Analytics Developer guides, the correct way of doing this is by using the following code:

```
_gaq.push(
    ['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-1'],
    ['_trackPageview'],
    ['b._setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-2'],
    ['b._trackPageview']
);
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#MultipleCommands

Tho, as above, Google says this way of doing things isn't 100% supported.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't support this approach because you need to be aware of some things a bit on the technical site. With that said, what you're trying to do is possible, just be sure to review your data. You do have a limited number of profiles that can only be increased by Google - you would have to go through a [Google Analytics Certified Partner](http://www.google.com/analytics/partners/index.html) since they're the only ones that can request that directly (and they still might say no).

The better way to do it is an account approach. When you hit your limit start making accounts from another set of login credentials, add your original email as an administrator, then remove the secondary user from the account (so you don't hit the limit again).

The technical issue you need to pay attention to is Google Analytics creating multiple sets of cookies per pageload. On subsequent page views it's a crapshoot which set of cookies it'll pick, so you'll see high new visitors, high bounce rates, and pretty unusable data. Call the `_setAllowHash` method properly and you'll avoid the issue by letting GA share the cookies.